# Convert Date String to Date Object Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert this date string `19/04/2015:21:43:47.40` to `Date` object. `new Date('19/04/2015:21:43:47.40')` returns invalid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure I would split the string on any characters that aren't digits with a regex `\D+`. Then you have an array with all the parts and you can pass it into `new Date()` in the correct order:

```js
var aParts = '19/04/2015:21:43:47.40'.split(/\D+/);
document.write(new Date(aParts[2], parseInt(aParts[1], 10)-1, aParts[0], aParts[3], aParts[4], aParts[5], aParts[6]));
```

Comment: @Nic if you're using this, there was a bug in there because JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11, so month 4 is interpreted as May where it should be April. I fixed it in my answer after you accepted it by subtracting 1 from the found part.